# getting valueof label in next column

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get the value in the next column ie Link1 labelwhen clicking on link1? how to do this with jquery? i tried:

```
$("#Link1").clicked( function()
{
    alert($("td(2) label.attr('text')"));
});

      <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="link1">Link1</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Link1 label</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="link2">Link2</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        Link2 label</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
   var $label = $(this).closest("tr").find("label");
   alert( $label.text() );
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, I think you meant `a#Link1` though.

Comment: @edgar , if there are any other labels under tr , there are chances that this cannot return the desired value

Comment: @kobe Yes, but we have to answer based on the conditions of the question, if not, there will never be a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
$("#Link1").click ( function () {

    alert ( $(this).parent ().siblings ('td').first ().children ('label').text () );
} );
```

[See a demo **for all links**, at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3NNZ/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
$("#link1").click( function()
{
    alert( $("#link1").parent().next().find("label").text() );
});
```

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7rfj/3/) example.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#Link1").clicked( function()
{
  alert($(this).parent().siblings('td > label').html())   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add return false also.

```
$("#Link1").click(function(){
   var $lblValue = $(this).parent().siblings().find("label");
   alert( $lblValue .html());
   return false // this will stop the jumping 
})
```